# update sql table as verified when user verifies their email c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, email-verification

I'm currently in the process of building a forum like site where people can register and login to their own page to post content.

I have built the system to send off a verification link to the registrants email along with a link that contains their user user id which is their email on the URL

```
http://localhost:50490/ForumTest/ActivateProfile.aspx?Username=jason90@yahoo.co.uk
```

I need to know how I can get my SQL database table `[UserTable]` field `UserVerified` to update to "1", it is currently set to "0" by default.

I just need to know how to write the code behind the `ActivateProfile.aspx` page to update this data field when the Users hit the `Activate button` on this page.

Would be awesome if someone can help me with this

I have been trying to find solutions everywhere but its all based on examples that were made using the **CREATE USER WIZARD** on the Microsoft Visual Studio environment. all my forms and fields have been made manually therefore those example were of no use for me :(.

Hope someone can help me

Thanks a lot in advance

:)

Comment: Have you looked at using `SqlClient` there are plenty of examples on how to update a `Database` in C# especially here on `StackOverFlow.com`

Comment: What you want is to perform an UPDATE statement against the database from your .aspx page.  Just Google "SQL Update c#" and you should find some good examples.

Comment: I've been trying to get examples from google but they are more of less based on Create user wizard =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an existing Database connection?  You need to execute some SQL similar to this:

```
UPDATE UserTable SET UserVerified=1 WHERE Username='jason90@yahoo.co.uk'
```

Comment: yes the SQL database is connected using a database code class